# How do you print an entire row of a list made of words?

Tags: python, arrays, list, printing, row

I have simplified my question where I just have a 2x2 list of words. I'm trying to print an entire row but it evidently doesn't work the same as with a list of numbers. How would I print an entire row?
This is for simple list manipulation.

```
array=[dog, cat],[hat,cap]

print(array[0][:])
```

I'm looking for an output of `dog cat`.

Comment: Your code does not compile as is, `array=['dog', 'cat'],['hat','cap']` will compile.  Calling that an array is mis-leading, it is a *tuple*.

Comment: @cdarke is correct, but in any case your print statement will work with a tuple as well as a list, although the `[:]` is unnecessary, which is equivalent printing a list of numbers, but as he points out in his answer, using the `' '.join` will remove the square brackets and comma.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean

```
array = [['dog','cat'],['hat','cap']]
```

and you want to print without the quotation marks and square brackets. In this case

```
print(' '.join(array[0]))
```

should do the job. Note the space in quotation marks.

Generally, its advised that you don't name your variables (in this case 'array') after things that are already part of python. Might be better to choose something like

```
string_list = [['dog','cat'],['hat','cap']]
```

Comment: There are several misconceptions in the question that you're not addressing here

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [['dog','cat'],['hat','cap']]
a = list(array)
print(a[0:1])
```

Maybe this will help? I'm beginner in python so I'am not sure if this solution is right. After this it will print: [['dog', 'cat']]